# how to setup an ardor childchain bundler via the command line on a ubuntu server?

Tags: ardor, command-line-options, ignis, bundler, child-chain

I have setup a testnet ardor node on the command line and its synced to the testnet ardor blockchain. I want to now create an always on bundler to bundle transactions of the ignis childchain via the command line. What is the command to run a bundler for ignis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any script which invokes the startBundler API but note that you will need to submit the passphrase to the node in order to start a bundler so you need to somehow protect the data in this script.